# Why is it not possible to use the template-method-pattern with static functions in PHP?

Tags: php

This works:

```
abstract class WonderfulBaseClass
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        $this->doPart1();
        $this->doPart2();
    }

    abstract protected function doPart1();
    abstract protected function doPart2();
}
```

but this doesn't (IDE says "Cannot call abstract method doPart[...]"):

```
abstract class WonderfulBaseClass
{
    public static function doStuff()
    {
        static::doPart1();
        static::doPart2();
    }

    abstract protected static function doPart1();
    abstract protected static function doPart2();
}
```

My thought was that extenders of the abstract base-class would still be forced to implement `doPart1` and `doPart2` so there shouldn't be a problem but I guess I have a fundamental misunderstanding going on.

Can someone explain why the first case is fine while the second seems to be problematic?

EDIT: changed self to static in the second part -> yields the same error message

Comment: `self` always refers to `WonderfulBaseClass`. You want `static::doPart1()`.

Comment: `static::doPart1()` produces the same error-message. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It's just your IDE complaining? Does it produce any complaints during actual execution? What is your IDE/linter that produces this message? Might simply be a limitation with it.

Comment: Ha! Very good hint! The following seemed to be the problem with the error-hint.
I introduced the static-template method in the base class but the extending class didn't align with the updated interface yet and it seems that PhpStorm recognizing that, showed this error in the base-class. The error-message is just a bit unlucky in my opinion. Now life makes sense again :D And thanks again for the clear-up about the static/self difference!